# facebook login sdk php Error: `URL bloqueada: This redirect failed because...`

Tags: php, facebook

Llevo un rato peliando con la integración del botón login de `facebook` en `PHP`.
De manera local funciona super bien pero al llevarla a producción y cambiar todos las configuraciones en `facebook.developer` de la app.

Me salta el siguiente error:

> URL bloqueada: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client
>   and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

Configure correctamente las urls, pero aun así sigue el error.

Tengo la aplicación bajo un subdominio, ¿sera por eso?

Ya que he leído que en las configuraciones debería ir la url con y sin `www`
alguien que pudiera orientarme .

Gracias.

Comment: El error está en tu aplicación, ya que al momento de enviar la solicitud, también le envías la url de redirección después del login, y es este URI el que no está incluido en tu configuración de facebook.

Comment: si se refiere a la variable redirect_uri que envio desde mi aplicación cabe decir que es la misma que configure en facebook dev

Comment: Verifica que sea la url exacta que pusiste en  URI de redireccionamiento de OAuth válidos , si usa https no lo obvies